# Stop my javascript loading on mobile

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code that renders a sticky tab to the left of my website. This pops up a box that offers a coupon if the user shares the page etc...

The only issue, is this is really obtrusive on a mobile browser, so I want to ensure that this script doesn't load on a mobile platform.

I currently have this fiddle of the js: http://jsfiddle.net/VHt8e/

and the following code that calls the following js code in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    var t = ''; if (document.cookie.indexOf("iscm=1") != -1) { var d = new Date(); t = '&t=' + d.getTime(); }
    newScript.src = '//www.MYDOMAIN.com/coupon.js' + t;
    headID.appendChild(newScript);
</script>
<div id="share-coupon-small"></div>
```

I have little experience with javascript so if someone could help me finish this code I will massively appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in an if statement based on window size.

```
var limit = 600;          
if(window.innerWidth>limit){
  //do  
}
```

With your code:

```
var limit = 600;
var window_width = window.innerWidth;

if(window_width>limit){
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    var t = ''; 
    if(document.cookie.indexOf("iscm=1") != -1) { 
      var d = new Date(); t = '&t=' + d.getTime(); 
    }
    newScript.src = 'http//www.sugarskulluk.com/coupon.js' + t;
    headID.appendChild(newScript);

    document.write("<div id=\"share-coupon-small\"></div>");
}//end of if window_width>limit
```

Comment: So, add this at the start of my javascript? I have tried adding it at the start of both of the above js codes and no success I'm afraid.

Comment: Anything within that "is larger than limit" will run `if` the statement is true. Alternatively, the `else` will run. Else is optional.

Comment: Okay okay! I see :) Could you possibly help me finish this? I know this doesn't make sense and does reflect my js knowledge: http://jsfiddle.net/VHt8e/2/
I have a html tag that has to go in after the js.. I wasn't sure how to complete so wrapped in doc.write

Comment: @LukeC the fiddle doesn't require `<script></script>`, it knows JS goes there (and throws a fit if you put non-js there). I've updated the answer with your code. Looks like there was an extra closing bracket messing it up :)

Comment: Also I guess I should note: I "escaped" your double-quotes with backslash. You could also use single quote there, but using double on a string wrapped in double breaks it.

Comment: Thanks pal! That worked perfect and I see what you have done... Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

For testing whether the device is a tablet or phone or desktop, I would probably lean more toward using User Agents.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

Comment: That will only get you so far. Checking against window width is more all-inclusive. It might look fine at 800px, and iPad runs larger than that.

Comment: The guy who asked it said that the tab looks obtrusive in mobile. We don't know what 'obtrusive' means, this is why i'm answering the simple goal of the question -> simply not running the javascript code if it's on mobile.

Now it's time for Luke to decide which solution is right for him.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/why-browser-sniffing-stinks/ User agent sniffing is bad news.

Answer (score 0):

A non-JS way to do this is to use a media query (either in a `<style>` element or CSS file) to hide the `share-coupon-small` element on small screens:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px), only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
    #share-coupon-small { display: none; }
}
```